# What are the constraints for tensorflow scope names?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running a tensorflow model and getting the following error:

```
ValueError: 'Cement (component 1)(kg in a m^3 mixture)' is not a valid scope name.
```

I get that tensorflow probably doesn't like special chars and spaces in its scope names, but I'm trying to find an actual doc on what chars are allowed. Does anyone know where I could find this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the TF [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2993):

> NOTE: This constructor validates the given `name`. Valid scope
>
> names match one of the following regular expressions:
>
> ```
> [A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]* (for scopes at the root)
> [A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]* (for other scopes)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

do not give space between the name example

here `name = 'name of model'` here you have given space that is why this model gives this error if you put `name = 'name_of_model'` it will not give you this error